# Export to excel hierarchy 2 levels

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, hierarchy, radgrid

I have hierarchy grid with 2 levels that I need to export to excel.
I choosed to make a select from SQL for the first level and another query for the second level and inserted the 2 queries results to 2 DataTables. 
but how do I connect between them?
how do I export to excel?
I use thid code that does not do anything:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=city.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string tab = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
        int i;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }
        Response.End();
```

> Blockquote

What am I doing wrong?